# Can a type `T` be boxed in any case where `isbitstype(T)` gives `true`?

Tags: julia

`:jl_type_to_llvm` can be used for checking whether a type is boxed or not, but if I have checked a type to be `isbitstype`, is there any need to check whether it is boxed using `jl_type_to_llvm`?

For example, is there a counter-example that can trigger the following assertion?

```
x = typeof(v)
if isbitstype(x)
     is_boxed = Ref{Bool}(false)
     @ccall jl_type_to_llvm(x::Any, is_boxed::Ptr{Bool})::Ptr{Cvoid}
     @assert !is_boxed[]
end
```

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Any Julia variable can be boxed, which might be needed when calling into the runtime. If you want to know if a type can be stored inline in an array or struct, there is `uniontype_layout`.

Comment: @SimeonSchaub Given a Julia object `v`, I'd like to get the corresponding LLVM type for this object. If the result of `typeof(v)` is isbitstype, do I need to check whether this type is boxed or not? If it could be boxed, in that case, the corresponding LLVM type should be `T_prjlvalue` and I may need to handle it carefully.

Comment: It still depends on where this type occurs. Every Julia type can be represented in llvm as a plain pointer. For example, the logic whether a specific field of a data type is a pointer looks like this: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/487757b7557ba8030923261ecf6133cc9d9d5ae6/src/julia.h#L1133 Note how it doesn't just depend on the field's type, but you need to look at the struct type that contains it.

Comment: hi @SimeonSchaub, could you give a counter-example? My current understanding is that `isbitstype`-types are all stored inline(i.e. `if isbitstype(x)==true then uniontype_layout(x)==true`). If isbitstypes are all stored inline, then as a field type, they should not be of pointer type and hence not boxed.